# Why doesn't this function get called?

Tags: xcode, swift, game-center, multiplayer

Im following the Ray Wenderlich tutorial and converted most of the code to Swift. Im on part two but this function never gets called. I followed the tutoral but im not sure where to call it. I dont think its a delegate function also so I know that im supposed to call it somewhere but not sure where. Has anyone ever tried this tutorial and got it to work on Swift? Thanks!

Heres the link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/60998/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-2

```
func match(theMatch: GKMatch, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPlayer playerID: String) {


    let message = UnsafePointer<Message>(data.bytes).memory

    if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeRandomNumber) {
        let messageRandomNumber = UnsafePointer<MessageRandomNumber>(data.bytes).memory

        println("Received random number: \(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber)")

        var tie = false

        if(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber == _ourRandomNumber) {
            println("Tie")
            tie = true
            _ourRandomNumber = arc4random()
            self.sendRandomNumber()
        }
        else {
            var dictionary = ["\(playerIDKey)":"\(playerID)", "\(randomNumberKey)":"\(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber)"]
            self.processReceivedRandomNumber(dictionary)
        }

        if(_receivedAllRandomNumbers) {
            _isPlayer1 = self.isLocalPlayerPlayer1()
        }

        if(!tie && _receivedAllRandomNumbers) {
            if(_gameState == GameState.kGameStateWaitingForRandomNumber) {
                _gameState = GameState.kGameStateWaitingForStart
            }
            self.tryStartGame()
        }
    }
    else if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeGameBegin) {
        println("Begin game message received")
        _gameState = GameState.kGameStateActive
        self.delegate?.setCurrentPlayerIndex(self.indexForLocalPlayer())
    }
    else if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeMove) {
        println("Move message received")
        let messageMove = UnsafePointer<MessageMove>(data.bytes).memory
        self.delegate?.movePlayerAtIndex(self.indexForPlayerWithId(playerIDKey))
    }
    else if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeGameOver) {
        println("Game over message received")
        let messageGameOver = UnsafePointer<MessageGameOver>(data.bytes).memory
        self.delegate?.gameOver(messageGameOver.player1Won)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method `match:didReceiveData:fromPlayer:` has been deprecated.  Use `match:didReceiveData:fromRemotePlayer:` instead.

Make sure you set the delegate, doing something like:

```
func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFindMatch match: GKMatch) {
    theMatch = match
    match.delegate = self
    ...
}
```

That is the `viewController:didFindMatch` delegate for `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate`.
You need to delegate from both `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate` and `GKMatchDelegate`.

Yeah, I know this is an old thread, but the OP hasn't had any success yet.

Answer (score 0):

`match:didReceiveData:fromPlayer:` is a `GKMatchDelegate` optional method which will trigger when the match received data sent from the player.

**So please don't try to call it directly**. It will be called by GameKit when data is received from a player.

```
@protocol GKMatchDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

// The match received data sent from the player.
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromRemotePlayer:(GKPlayer *)player NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID NS_DEPRECATED(10_8, 10_10, 4_1, 8_0, "use match:didReceiveData:fromRemotePlayer:");

@end;
```

This also is declared in `GameKitHelper.h` class as a `GameKitHelperDelegate`

```
@protocol GameKitHelperDelegate

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
   fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID;

@end
```

This delegate method is calling from the below method when the match received data sent from the player

```
#pragma mark GKMatchDelegate

// The match received data sent from the player.
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {
    if (_match != match) return;

    [_delegate match:match didReceiveData:data fromPlayer:playerID];
}
```

Comment: How would call it in swift?

Comment: You wouldn't call it directly. It will be called by `GameKit` "when data is received from a player" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchDelegate_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKMatchDelegate/match:didReceiveData:fromPlayer:

Comment: @Ramshad I have it setup exactly like in the tuttorial but it never gets called.

Comment: @Ramshad I put it as a delegate function but it still doesn't get called on it own.